# Unable to debug web page code but can debug code in global.asax

Tags: asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, postsharp

When I put a breakpoint on the page_load of the starting page, I receive the following message.
"the breakpoint will not be hit. no symbols have been loaded for this document."
I have seen this before and usually resolve this by cleaning the solution and running it again. This time, however, I am not able to find a solution. What is even stranger about this time is that if I put a breakpoint in global.asax such as Application_BeginRequest, the breakpoint does hit and I can debug, this happens for any page that I add breakpoints to.

If I go to menus\Debug\Windows\Modules I can see that the web app DLL was not built with debug information.

Comment: I also want to mention that I am able to debug other web apps but just not this one. In addition, I don't have debugging problems on other computers using the same web app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue turned out to be related to the AOP framework PostSharp. I uninstalled it and re-installed it and everything is now properly debugging. By the way I love PostSharp and I highly recommend it. However, I wanted to post my issue and resolution in case someone is experiencing the same issue and is currently using PostSharp.

Answer (score 3):

While debugging, 2 things that let breakpoint work correctly consist of .dll and .pdb file. If you look at your bin folder of your project. These 2 files will placed together and must have same "date modified" which mean it was created together while building.

If these 2 files are not created together in whatever reason. Some line-of-code of some files will not hitted by break point. You can also see while debug by navigate to Debug > Windows > Modules. Then find your target dll that you want to debug such as YourApp.dll. Then see in symbol status column. If it work correctly, I will show Symbols loaded.

This may occur in many reasons such as you have changed something in your code (this case may be your aspx file) then you debug without build.

To fix this, You can go to Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run at "On Run, when projects are out of date" set as "Always build" to ensure your project always be built before going to debug.

Comment: Great suggestion however I am still experiencing the problem. I did notice that no .pdb files are generated from my project.